# Rails errors not showing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So im learning rails, and following the rails getting started guide (I've actually done the "blog app" on the Udemy rails course, but im making sure I can write it from scratch first before moving on).

Anyways, i've gotten Delete/Create running, but I was adding validation...and while the validation works my errors aren't showing up.

Right now my pages are super simple:

`new.html.erb`

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= form_with scope: :user, url: users_path, local: true do |form| %>
<p>
  <%= form.label :username %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :username %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :name %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :age %><br>
  <%= form.number_field :age %>
</p>
<p><%= form.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

`users_controller`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
    end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @user = User.new(params.require(:user).permit(:username,:name,:age))
      if @user.save
        redirect_to users_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def update

    end

    def destroy
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path
    end

end
```

So the weird thing if I go into my network tab in dev tools I can see this show up in the response tab:

```
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      1 error prohibited this user from being saved
    </h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Username has already been taken</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

But it doesn't show up in "elements" in Chrome dev tools. I've restarted rails....so Im really not sure why the elements are not showing up. I DO have bootstrap 4.00 beta installed, but not sure why that would matter. This is rails 5.1.4 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not getting the same @user in the `<% if @user.errors.any? %>`

Try this :

```
<%= form_with scope: :user, url: users_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<p>
  <%= form.label :username %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :username %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :name %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :age %><br>
  <%= form.number_field :age %>
</p>
<p><%= form.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The render method is used so that the @user object is passed back to the new template when it is rendered. This rendering is done within the same request as the form submission.

Comment: but here by writing form_with down there the error message block don't get the previous @user.

Comment: that sorta makes sense but if were passing @user from the form to the `new` template....I don't see why we can't access @user anyone else in the `new.html.erb` file except for the form?

Comment: refer (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) point **5.10 Adding Some Validation**

Comment: I understand why we do the `@user` = User.new, my confusion is why we only have access to `@user` inside the form, but not outside. (The link doesn't seem to explain that)